# Does it matter if I use \textit or \it, \bfseries or \bf, etc

Tags: fonts, formatting, best-practices, obsolete

I typically use

```
\textit{Some italicized text}
```

while some of my colleagues use

```
{\it Some other text}
```

Should I bother changing one or the other, or does it matter?

Related:

[*Is there any reason not to use \let to redefine a deprecated control sequence to the currently recommended one?*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304311/is-there-any-reason-not-to-use-let-to-redefine-a-deprecated-control-sequence-to)

Answer (score 124, accepted):

From [l2tabu](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/):

> Why not use obsolete commands? Obsolete commands do not support LaTeX2e's new font
>   selection scheme, or NFSS. `{\bf foo}`, for example, resets all font attributes which had been
>   set earlier before it prints *foo* in bold face. This is why you cannot simply define a bold-italics style by `{\it \bf Test}` only. (This definition will produce: **Test**.) On the other hand, the new commands `\textbf{\textit{Test}}` will behave as expected producing: ***Test***.
>
> Apart from that, with the former commands there is no ‘italic correction’, cf. for instance
>   halfhearted (`{\it half}hearted`) to halfhearted (`\textit{half}hearted`).

[image]

Comment: To be fair, it's not really that hard to write `{\it half\/}hearted`. This is how it would be done in TeX, after all.

Comment: It should be noted that when the blockquote talks about “obsolete”, it means obsolete in **>= LaTeX2e**. Those commands are *not* obsolete in Plain-tex or ConTeXt.

Comment: (I'm not sure, if there commands existed 2010, but) what about `{\bfseries textOne {\itshape textTwo}}`? Are they outdated too? What are they for? `{\itshape half}hearted` doesn't work nice.

Comment: @Ben They the  corresponding "switching" commands and stack correctly (i.e. `\itshape\bfseries` produces the correct output). Useful for some layout definitions (e.g. in KOMA or titlesec).

Answer (score 51):

Hmm, I just posted this as an answer to another question, but just as I was posting, that question was closed—with a referral here.  So I'll throw in my 2¢ here...

The reason I don't like `\it` and `\bf` is that they do not play well together.  That is, they do not nest as one would intuitively expect:

[image]

Whereas `\textit` and `\textbf` do play well together:

[image]

This is nice. However, you may notice that it still fails to handle nested style adjustments to small caps, since the Computer Modern fonts do not contain slanted or bold small caps:

[image]

If this is a problem for you, then what I recommend—and I just happened to learn about this yesterday myself—is the wonderful `slantsc` package in combination with the `lmodern` package.  `slantsc` provides, among other things, `\rmfamily` (roman), `\ttfamily` (typewriter/​teletype), `\sffamily` (sans-serif), `\bfseries` (boldface), `\itshape` (italics), `\slshape` (slant/​oblique), and `\scshape` (small caps).  With these, small caps can obtained in slanted form:

[image]

As a bonus, `slantsc` fixes `\textsl` to behave properly with `\textsc`, so you can continue using those if you like.

Alas, I haven't yet found a package which fixes the behavior of nested instances of `\textit`.  In typesetting, when you nest italics, you're supposed to *come back out* of italics to roman. For example, the word "Titanic" below is in nested italics:

> Tanaka, Shelly. *On Board the* Titanic: *What It Was Like When the Great Liner
>   Sank*. New York, NY: Hyperion/​Madison Press, 1998.

As a workaround, you can usually write `\textrm` to temporarily return to non-italics in those cases, but of course this is only valid if you know the exact number of nested italic levels, which may not always be the case, especially inside a macro.

**Update:**

As others have pointed out, `\textit` and `\textsl` do automatic italic correction, whereas `\it`, `\itshape`, `\sl`, and `\slshape` do not.  Thus, you can write `\textit{stuff}`, but you must write `{\it stuff\/}` or `{\itshape stuff\/}` to get the same effect.

Comment: I would *not* expect `\textit` (or any other command intended to do italics) to generate *non-italic* text. On the other hand I'd expect `\emph` (which is used to *emphasize*) to switch to italics if not already in italic mode while to switch *off* italics when in italic mode (because *emphasizing* is usually done this way). And guess what, that's exactly what `\emph` does. The correct way to type the title above therefore is: `On Board the \emph{Titanic:} What It Was Like When the Great Liner Sank.` Note that Titanic is *emphasized,* not *italicised.*

Comment: @celtschk: Cool, I did not know that! (Or I think I did once long ago and forgot!) Thanks so much for pointing this out.

Comment: Note that cfr-lm will give you access to the same features but uses slightly different commands. cfr-lm relies on virtual fonts but also makes other features of the LM family available (e.g. different styles of figures, different weights etc.). Disclaimer: I wrote cfr-lm.

Comment: @celtschk, ‘Titanic’ is not set in italics because it’s emphasized, but because its a custom of English typography to italicize names of vessels, like (family) names are set in small caps elsewhere. Therefore using `\emph` would be inappropriate.

Comment: Note that Latin Modern also features an upright italic font.

Answer (score 39):

The `\it` syntax is inherited from LaTeX 2.09, and is regarded as supported 'for historical reasons only' in LaTeX2e. For bold, you should go for `\textbf` rather than `\bf`.  For italic, you'd usually use `\emph` rather than `\textit` as it's semantic mark up and as it handles the italic correction automatically.

Comment: I beg to differ. If you want to set italic text, `\textit` is the way to go. But if you want to emphasize some text, then you should use `\emph{}`.

Comment: It's very rare that you want inline italic that isn't in some way semantic. For longer blocks, \itshape is the way to do things, of course.

Comment: Of course, semantic markup should always be preferred over syntactic one, but the question was specific about the difference between `\textit` and `\it`

Comment: Or, if you want a command that is used in the same way as \it, use \itshape.

Comment: @qbi and @Joseph I'm sorry, I must be daft. I don't understand the above discussion. I want to know when to use \emph, and when to use \textit. I feel like there is some discussion above that answers my question, but I can't figure it out. Could you either make it more clear, or should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: `\emph` is semantic: it says 'make things emphasised'. On the other hand, `\textit` means `make this italic`. By convention, `\emph` makes things italic, but you can redefine it to do something else (for example, the `beamer` class makes text red). On the other hand, `\textit` is always italic. So it is usually advised to use `\emph` in a document, using `\textit` only when you need definitely italic text. This might make a good question, as I'd then have more space to give detail!

Comment: @Joseph, Done. :)

Comment: @JosephWright Well, you want to use \emph{} when you want to emphasis something. If you need something italic for another reason (Such as convention) then \textit{} (Or a semantic wrapper around \textit{} ) would be better, right?

Comment: @Canageek Yes, that's the idea. The reason `\emph` 'stands out' is I guess it's very common.

Comment: `\emph` does not always mean to italicize.  Sometimes it means to un-italicize.  Consider the difference between `\emph{This is \textit{italic} text}` and `\emph{This is \emph{italic} text}`, particularly when you might not have control over when your text is wrapped or set in italics, like a `bibtex` title.

Comment: If I was writing "foo, bar, etc.", that should be written as `foo, bar, \textit{etc}.`, correct?  I am not emphasizing etc, I am italicizing it because it is a foreign language.  Even if "emphasizing" is defined to be in red, I still want it in italic.

Comment: @TroyDaniels That's a bit complicated because of the italic correction. I guess I'd favour `\newcommand*\foreign[1]{\emph{#1}}` so you get logical mark-up in the document.

Comment: @TroyDaniels But in a block of italic, you'd then want `etc.` in upright, wouldn't you? (I've never put `etc.` in any different face myself, so this is entirely hypothetical.)

Comment: @cfr what do you write instead of `etc.`?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the deprecated "old font commands", I find them quite useful for equations.

Let's say e.g. that I want to write a symbol for an external potential as `$V_{ext}$`. However, it is a common convention to use upright characters for subscripts and superscripts that are labels rather than variables, which can be written as either

```
V_{\mathrm{ext}}   or
V_{\rm ext}
```

I *strongly* prefer the latter, as the lower character-count and nesting-level makes reading and editing easier. Though there are cases where the advantage is diminished, e.g. with vector component notations like

```
f_{\mathrm{ext},i} vs
f_{{\rm ext},i} or
f_{\rm ext\it,i}       % <- not tested
```

Some modern document classes do not provide the old-style commands anymore. In this case, they can be reintroduced with `\DeclareOldFontCommand`, see e.g. [What exactly does \DeclareOldFontCommand and \DeclareRobustCommand do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57109/what-exactly-does-declareoldfontcommand-and-declarerobustcommand-do).

Comment: Yeah, I think it was a dumb choice to deprecate and move to a command with more characters, why not just redefine \rm with the new functionality, or provide a package that makes pointers such that the better shorter name can be used.

Comment: @RicardoAcuna Redefining existing commands can have all sorts of nasty follow-up effects. E.g. a bibliography style may depend on the old style commands and then *silently* do the wrong thing (which is generally worse than an error message). As for the "more character" commands: I think we got bitten there by a "cleaner, more uniform syntax" (good practice for programming) vs "everyday typesetting usability" trade-off.

Comment: You forget latex isn’t designed to be a programming language, I know it’s Turing complete. But, the point of latex is every day typesetting. Maintainers treat it as a programming language, that’s stupid. It’s not it’s a typesetting program, so usability trumps uniform syntax.

Comment: I mean I guess back-compatibility is important. But instead of deprecating, they could add a versioning package \usepackage{latexv2022} just full of pointers. That way you don’t break back compatibility because the pointers are just local to the Tex file.

Comment: Also @kbd we don’t have uniform syntax every time I need to do anything non standard it’s a rabbit hole of packages and macros and the answer is often buried deep in tex.stackexchange and it’s a one off hack. End rant.

Comment: @RicardoAcuna I agree there, it is *not* a programming environment. I just suspect, that *treating it as one* is what got us the deprecation of `\rm` and the like.

Comment: `\rm` , `\it` are not deprecated they are simply not defined at all. Some classes (including `article`) may define compatibility definitions for compatibity with latex2.09 from 1985, but with other classes (including KomaScript classes) you will get errors from the form you  "strongly prefer" @RicardoAcuna

Answer (score 3):

I don't completely agree with [Caramdir's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520/90856), since it is true that `\it` should not be used because it is obsolete, however the corresponding non-depreciated command is `\itshape`.

So, in your example `\it` should be replaced with `\itshape`. However, in some cases as for `\textit{half}hearted` vs `{\itshape half}hearted`, the former is preferable.

Comment: Is this a new answer or is it a replication of Caramdir comment or Todd Lehman answer?

Comment: @Bobyandbob: It is a new answer since without the comment Caramdir's answer is misleading: it asserts that \it is obsolete since it has no italic correction. Todd Lehman on the other hand points out that \bf and \it don't play well together, however they should be replaced with \bfseries and \itshape (so is not a reason to change to \textbf/\textit)! He also wrongly implies that you need the package slantsc for \itshape and \bfseries, which is not true