# Using LaTeX, how can I restate a theorem, with the same theorem number, later in a paper?

Tags: numbering, cross-referencing, theorems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I repeat a theorem number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number)

I am writing a paper, and would like to state the main results in the Introduction.  Then, when I come to prove the main results in later sections, I would like to restate the theorem before proceeding with the proof.  (We could debate about whether that is good style, but it is what my co-author and I want to do in this instance.)  I would prefer to restate the theorem with the original theorem number - so "Theorem 1.1" again, rather than "Theorem 4.1," when restated.  Does anyone have a good solution for how to do this in LaTeX?

I have done this a couple times before, but never with an elegant solution.  The best solution I have come up with is to create a different theoremstyle for main results, and call the main results "Theorem A", etc, in the introduction; and then use yet another theoremstyle to reproduce the results, again "Theorem A" later in the paper.  This method works so long as you prove the results in the order that you discuss them in the introduction, but is inelegant.

I also realize that hard core TeX users might tell me just to use TeX, where you have much more control.  That would also take more time than I have energy for to finish this paper!

> What is a good way to re-use Theorem numbers, to repeat a theorem, using LaTeX?
>
> More technically, how can I get a Theorem to use a \ref for the number, rather than referring automatically to a counter?

Comment: This may be identical to Scott Morrison's question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number .

Comment: could you take a look at the answers to Scott's question and see if they work for you?  If not, it would be helpful if you could explain what's wrong with them so that we know how best to answer your question.  (And welcome to tex.SE!)

Comment: I have ended up using Andrew Stacey's solution to Scott's question.  I also like JeffE's answer below, but cannot make it work with amsthm.  Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps the other question should have its title clarified? "How do I repeat a theorem number" doesn't exactly imply that the body of the theorem is to be unaltered -- one can imagine wanting to restate the same theorem in different language, for example.

Answer (score 4):

I define my own `oneshot` environment in a private macro package.

```
\newenvironment{oneshot}[1]{\@begintheorem{#1}{\unskip}}{\@endtheorem}
```

Here's how it's used:

```
\begin{theorem}
\label{Th:wet}
The rain in Spain falls mainly on the plain.
\end{theorem}

\begin{oneshot}{Theorem~\ref{Th:wet}}
Iberian precipitation primarily hits the flatlands.
\end{oneshot}
```

Comment: I cannot make this work with amsthm, which has a more complicated @begintheorem.

Comment: I am in the same boat as Carl. I found the answer here helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number

Comment: Works nicely for me with the acmsmall document class.