# How do I repeat a theorem number with the llncs class?

Tags: environments, theorems, lncs

I am writing an article with the llncs class, and I am trying to repeat  a theorem twice in different sections.

For example,

> ## Section 1
>
> **Theorem 1.1.** *Let* ...

And then later in the paper I want to recall the theorem by reprinting it

> ## Section 4
>
> We recall Theorem 1.1:
>
> **Theorem 1.1.** *Let* ...

I used the solutions proposed in [1,2,3,4,5], and they seemed  to clash and  do not work with the llncs class.
Is there any way to use these solutions with respect to the llncs class?

[1]-[How do I repeat a theorem number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number)

[2]-[Using LaTeX, how can I restate a theorem, with the same theorem number, later in a paper?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1688/using-latex-how-can-i-restate-a-theorem-with-the-same-theorem-number-later-in)

[3]-[Recalling a theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/recalling-a-theorem)

[4]-[Repeat a Theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149547/repeat-a-theorem?rq=1)

[5]- [How to automatically repeat all the theorems?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251818/how-to-automatically-repeat-all-the-theorems?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please explain what your specific problem is? When we know it, perhaps we can suggest which one of the five methods can be made to work or propose a different solution.

Comment: It is the same problem explained in [1,2,3,4,5].  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `llncs` class uses a different way of defining theorem-like environments, so it's not a surprise that the other suggested methods don't work. Neither `amsthm` nor `ntheorem` based solution can work.

Here I assume the theorem to repeat precedes the repetition. I define a new environment `reptheorem` that stores the text; it has a mandatory argument that also sets a `\label` with the same name.

In the example I also show that the optional argument is honored.

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{llncs}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand{\repeattheorem}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\ref{#1}}%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\theorem
  \csname reptheorem@#1\endcsname
  \endtheorem
  \endgroup
}

\NewEnviron{reptheorem}[1]{%
  \global\expandafter\xdef\csname reptheorem@#1\endcsname{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
  }%
  \expandafter\theorem\BODY\unskip\label{#1}\endtheorem
}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\begin{reptheorem}{foo}[Somebody]
Let $x$ be a foo. Then $x$ is also a baz.
\end{reptheorem}

\section{Another}

\repeattheorem{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A feature asked in comments prompted to write “more modern code” for the job.

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\replabel}{\label} % will be redefined in restatements

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\repeattheorem}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\ref{#1}}
  \renewcommand{\replabel}[1]{\tag{\ref{##1}}}
  \prop_item:Nn \g_reptheorem_prop { #1 }
  \endtheorem
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{reptheorem}{m+b}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nnn \g_reptheorem_prop { #1 } { \theorem #2 \endtheorem }
  \theorem#2\unskip\label{#1}\endtheorem
 }{}

\prop_new:N \g_reptheorem_prop

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\begin{reptheorem}{foo}[Somebody]
Let $x$ be a foo. Then $x$ is also a baz.
\begin{equation}\replabel{fooeq}
1=1
\end{equation}
with an equation.
\end{reptheorem}

\section{Another}

\repeattheorem{foo}

\end{document}
```

In theorems to be repeated, labels to equations (mandatory) should be set with `\replabel`. This way we can change the meaning to use `\tag` instead. The `\label` command cannot be used, because `amsmath` (necessary for `\tag`) would change back the meaning of `\label` in a display.

[image]

Comment: This is the best solution I've found so far to repeat a theorem in the `svjour3` document class.  One issue I'm having is that if there is a numbered equation in the original theorem, I'd like the same equation to keep the same number later on.  Or, better yet, replace the equation tag `(#)` with `(# revisited)` in the repeated theorem.  Is there any way to do something like that with your solution?

Comment: @DMcMor Not straightforward, but it can be done with some care.

Comment: Your updated solution works perfectly, thanks!