# How do I repeat a theorem number with the llncs class and vary the text between the two occurrences?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, environments, theorems, lncs

A similar question was asked in [How do I repeat a theorem number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number/443#443) with a really awesome [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443) by [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey).
However, it requires amsthm to use `\newtheorem`, thus theorem amsthm style (name normal) and not llncs style (name bold).
When I change `\newtheorem*{rep@theorem}{\rep@title}` to `\spnewtheorem*{rep@theorem}{\rep@title}{\bfseries}{\itshape}` I get error on undefined `\rep@title`.

Also, there is a similar question [How do I repeat a theorem number with the llncs class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336973/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number-with-the-llncs-class), however, the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336981/226435) by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) does not allow me to restate with varying text, which is what I need to achieve. (I think `restatable` environment from `thm-restate` seems to work for me for this use-case).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `llncs` class uses an approach different from `amsthm`, therefore the other solution is not applicable.

Add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\newcommand\repeatedtheorem[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\repeatedtheoremtmp\csname#1name\endcsname
  \expandafter\def\csname#1name\endcsname{%
    \repeatedtheoremtmp\ \ref{#2}%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname#1name\endcsname\repeatedtheoremtmp
  }
}
```

To repeat the number of a theorem, you have to do the following things.

- Define an unnumbered version of your theorem environment. E.g., if you want to recall/preview a theorem, add the following line to your preamble:

  ```
  \spnewtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}{\normalshape\bfseries}{\itshape}
  ```

  This will define an environment `theorem*` that looks like the `theorem` environment, but without numbers.
- Add a label to the theorem whose number you want to reuse, say `\label{myAmazingTheorem}`.
- At the place where you want to preview/recall the real theorem (with the number given there), use the unnumbered version `\begin{theorem*}...\end{theorem*}`.
- Immediately before this unnumbered theorem, tell LaTeX to use the number of the real theorem by adding the line

  ```
  \repeatedtheorem{theorem*}{myAmazingTheorem}
  ```

[image]

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{llncs}
\spnewtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}{\normalshape\bfseries}{\itshape}
\newcommand\repeatedtheorem[2]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\repeatedtheoremtmp\csname#1name\endcsname
  \expandafter\def\csname#1name\endcsname{%
    \repeatedtheoremtmp\ \ref{#2}%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname#1name\endcsname\repeatedtheoremtmp
  }
}
\begin{document}

\section{Preview}
\repeatedtheorem{theorem*}{myAmazingTheorem}
\begin{theorem*}[just a preview]
  My amazing theorem that we will discuss later.
\end{theorem*}

\begin{theorem*}
  An unnumbered theorem.
\end{theorem*}

\section{The real thing}
\begin{theorem}[The Amazing Theorem]
\label{myAmazingTheorem}
A theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```