# Environment prop undefined and also already defined LNCS template

Tags: theorems, undefined, journal-publishing, newtheorem, journal

Trying to put my paper into LNCS format and I'm having a weird error if I comment out the line  \newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}  it tells me prop is undefined but if I uncomment the line it tells me it is already defined.

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

%\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\begin{document}
\title{Contribution Title\thanks{Supported by organization x.}}
\maketitle              
\begin{abstract}
The abstract 
\end{abstract}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{A Subsection Sample}
Please note 
\begin{prop}
    dsafdf
\end{prop}
\end{document}
```

LNCS file available here https://www.overleaf.com/read/ygfkzwkxjhbw#d20610

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLNCS already defines a Proposition theorem environment, you should use `\begin{proposition} ... \end{proposition}` instead of defining your own.
It has the advantage of properly localizing to various languages.

---

That said, the issue with `prop` is not a conflict with LLNCS, but with `thm-restate`. And it is not really that the environment `prop` has been defined, but that there is a bug in how `thmtools` is trying to latch onto the LLNCS macros and provide its own interpretation of stuff.

I've been able to isolate the bug to the file `thm-llncs.sty`; the specific error is coming from the call to `\thmt@newtheorem@predefinition` in the definition of `\thmt@spnewtheoremiv`. (**This part I am sure about.**)

The problem, I think (**the following is a guess, which may be incorrect**), is that as part of the `...predefinition`, it calls `...autorefsetup`, which creates a counter-alias when sibling counters are used. But then the original `\spnewtheorem` from the Springer LLNCS file is called, which tries to create the counter again.

One can check that without specifying a sibling counter, commands such as
`\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}`, or `\declaretheorem[name=Proposition]{prop}`, or `\spnewtheorem{prop}{Proposition}{\bfseries}{\itshape}` all work as expected, but as soon as you specify a sibling counter everything breaks.

You should file a bug with the `thmtools` maintainers linking to this post and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Okay whats the easiest way to fix this?

Comment: The easiest way to fix any and all `thmtools` related errors is to **not use `thmtools`.** // If you don't intend to use the `autoref` features from `hyperref`, you can make a local copy of `thmtools.sty` in your working directory and find the line where it `\RequirePackge`  the file `thm-autoref`; delete the reference to `thm-autoref`. This should in principle work (but I haven't tested for whether it breaks other things).

Comment: But seriously: file a bug report at https://github.com/muzimuzhi/thmtools/issues the maintainers know the code better than I do, and they should be able to give you a better workaround, if not a complete fix.

Comment: How do I do restatable without thmtools?

Comment: Try egreg's code here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336981/119  You will need to make appropriate changes (egreg assumes that one is repeating a theorem, if you are repeating a proposition you need to change a bunch of things, e.g. `\thetheorem` -> `\theproposition`.)