# restating a theorem using theomac.sty

Tags: environments, counters

I am trying to restate a theorem environment using theomac.sty which floats around, following a suggestion I received here:

[how do I refer back to counters?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4287/how-do-i-refer-back-to-counters)

The package I downloaded loads well, but whenever I run pdflatex I get the following error:

```
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m 
l.199 \@
        newtheoremWithMacro{replemma}{lemma}
```

I am confused what it means. I tried following it a bit in google, but it still does not make much sense to me.

Here is the lemma environment my style file defines:

```
\def\lemmaname{Lemma}
\newtheorem{lemma}{\lemmaname}%[section]
\def\thelemma{\arabic{lemma}}
\def\lemmafont{}
\def\lemmaheadfont{\bfseries}
```

The theomac style file can be found in: http://cookp.com/thread/1500775/Equation%20kopieren%20referenzieren

can someone identify why I am getting this error? Just a hint as to what it means could be also helpful... I can't find the command spacefactor in either syle files (`theomac.sty` or the style file that defines theorems.)

Comment: solved. had to use \makeatletter and \let command exactly as it appears in http://cookp.com/thread/1500775/Equation%20kopieren%20referenzieren.

Comment: please do try to check for this small syntax errors before posting questions. Trying to write down a [complete minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is also always very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

klew commented on his question: `had to use \makeatletter and \let command exactly as it appears in` [cookp.com/thread/1500775/Equation%20kopieren%20referenzieren.](http://cookp.com/thread/1500775/Equation%20kopieren%20referenzieren.), where the following snippet appears, in the context of a Latex file that uses packages `hyperref` and `theomac`:

```
% copy the equation-environment to the \myequation-environment:
\let\myequation=\equation
\let\endmyequation=\endequation

% transform the copied environment which also uses the equation-counter
% into such which takes optional argument for defining a macro:

\makeatletter
\@newtheoremWithMacro{myequation}{equation}%
\makeatother
```

By not expanding the macro `\equation` when assigning it to `\myequation`, it allows the macro to be reused in creating a new theorem style.

Comment: I've posted an answer to this qn, which is one that the original qner solved in order to let it be taken off the [Unanswered](http://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list.  Summarising a solution that has sat  in comments for ages is good for the site, since it makes the Unanswered list more useful and improves our site's statistics.