# Problems with theomac package to restate theorems

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I have the following problems with the "theomac" package by Ulrich Diez (whom I don't know how to contact). This package is useful to restate theorems, and was mentioned e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4290/restating-a-theorem-using-theomac-sty).

Problems:

- Get error if there's empty line in theorem declaration
- Enumerate numbers are wrong when restating the theorem

Also, to repeat a theorem one needs to specify a command. Is there a way for the package macro to deduce this command from the label of the theorem, or the label from the command? This would save a parameter and make things cleaner.

The following code shows both problems and the "also" question as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{../theomac}
\newtheoremWithMacro{theoremR}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

%The following doesn't compile because of empty line
\begin{theoremR}
bla

bla
\end{theoremR}

\begin{theoremR}[\teo]
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla
\item bla
\end{enumerate}
\end{theoremR}

%Numbering of enumerate is wrong in the following
\teo

%Is there a way for the macro to deduce
%label and or \teo from other?
\begin{theoremR}[\teo] \label{teo}
bla
\end{theoremR}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Automatic labelling would be difficult, because there might be several \label commands in the environment. I'd guess that theomac internally creates a label for its data (thmtools' thm-restate does), but those are usually numbered consecutively to have a simple way of making them unique, and revealing them defeats the purpose of the label mechanism in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! thm-restate works much better! Regarding label, couldn't you modify it so that \begin{theorem}[name=bla,restate=res]
becomes \begin{theorem}[name=bla,restate=res,label=res]? This is what I'd like. Another thing: can you make it so that \begin{theorem}[restate=res] is valid? Right now I'm forced to specify a name. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Ulrich Schwarz answered this in his comment:

> Automatic labelling would be
>   difficult, because there might be
>   several `\label` commands in the
>   environment. I'd guess that theomac
>   internally creates a label for its
>   data (`thmtools`' `thm-restate` does), but
>   those are usually numbered
>   consecutively to have a simple way of
>   making them unique, and revealing them
>   defeats the purpose of the label
>   mechanism in the first place.