# Recalling a theorem

Tags: theorems, content-replication

Suppose I have some theorem in the paper

> ## Section 1
>
> **Theorem 1.1.** *Let* ...

And then later in the paper I want to recall the theorem by reprinting it

> ## Section 4
>
> We recall Theorem 1.1:
>
> **Theorem 1.1.** *Let* ...

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I would just store the contents of the theorem in a macro and re-use the macro for the initial and reuse.

Comment: Interesting question!  However, I have serious doubts whether this is actually a good idea.  A traditional `\ref`erence might actually be better.  As a reader, if I saw **Theorem 1.1** in two places of a book, I'd think it's a mistake, and after seeing that this is actually the same theorem, I might feel "cheated" by the author...

Comment: @mbork What's the problem, he explicitly says: "We recall Theorem 1.1", why should someone think it is a mistake. Think about a case when the Theorem is in the body of the paper and the proof of the theorem is in the appendix. So before the proof you want to recall the exact statement of the theorem once again. Would this this confuse somebody?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  To Restate a theorem is not to repeat a theorem number.

Comment: Fred, it's true that restating a theorem is different than repeating a theorem number, but if you click through to the link you'll see the linked question is actually about restating a theorem.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The `thm-restate` package which is part of [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) offers a `restatable` environment. In the following example, I also use `hyperref` and `cleveref` (its `\cref` macro automatically adds the correct theorem type). See section 1.4 of the `thmtools` manual for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{thm}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{restatable}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
\label{thm:goldbach}
Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
\end{restatable}

\section{Second}

We recall \cref{thm:goldbach}:

\goldbach*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't comment yet, so hopefully this will change to one. I got lots of errors when I tried to use thm-restate just now. The problem seemed to be that it didn't like being in the same `\usepackage` command as other packages. It also likes to be placed after `amsthm`.

Comment: I had trouble implementing something similar in my own document, so I tried running literally your document. The following happened: `LaTeX Warning: \Cref reference format for label type 'thm' undefined on input l
ine 23.

! Undefined control sequence.
\HyRef@StarSetRef ...Hy@safe@activestrue \edef \x 
                                                  {#1}\@onelevel@sanitize \x...
l.25 \goldbach*`. How can I circumnavigate this issue?

Comment: @jdc Still works for me. Try to delete all auxiliary files and compile several times.

Comment: is there a way of capitalizing the name of the theorem when recalling it? Ie. 'We recall Theorem 1.1:'

Comment: Does `declaretheorem` do the same as `newtheorem`?

Comment: When I use this, the stylizing of the theorem is lost (in both original and repeated theorem).

Comment: You can use `\Cref` to capitalize the name of the theorem.

Comment: \usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref} can also be used if one wishes \cref to always capitalise (as in produce 'Theorem 1.1' rather than 'theorem 1.1').

Comment: @ThomasAhle (and other curious readers) the answer is not quite. `thmtools` does introduce some additional patches to `\newtheorem` and `\declaretheorem` is not a straight up wrapper.

Answer (score 19):

If you need it only once or twice or so, you can locally in the repeating: 1) tweak theorem label printing, 2) add `-1` to the `theorem` counter since it gets increased by the repeated theorem. The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{theorem}\label{mythm}
Let $x$ ...
\end{theorem}

\section{Second}

\begin{theorem}
This should be two.one
\end{theorem}

Let us recall the theorem from the first section.

\begingroup
\def\thetheorem{\ref{mythm}}
\begin{theorem}
Let $x$ ...
\end{theorem}
\addtocounter{theorem}{-1}
\endgroup

\begin{theorem}
This should be two.two
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if there are multiple theorems between the original and the recall? Is there a robust way of dealing with this? Something like saving the counter to a variable, then setting it to the value at some label before resetting it to the saved value?

Comment: It does nit matter what you put inbewteen, this is robust againat such things.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you said "If you need it only once or twice or so" at the beginning? This feels like a pretty solid way to do this honestly, much cleaner and simpler than other solutions, even those on other similar threads. Are there any unforeseen complications that this may cause? Is this not good practice?

Comment: @EkanshdeepGupta It's a dirty trick with a lot of code inserted. The more you use there the easier you mess up or get lost in them.

Comment: This requires repeating the theorem statement in the code, which is undesirable as it is unmaintainable.