# using a restatable before it is stated

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, thmtools

This question is related to the question at [[Recalling a theorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/recalling-a-theorem)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/recalling-a-theorem), which uses the thmtools and thm-restate packages and the restatable environment to define a theorem that can be re-stated later on.

Is it possible to refer to something that is defined later on?
In an earlier chapter, I have some discussion that is referring to a definition that is defined properly in a later chapter, but I can't reuse the definition before it is defined...

For example, when I do the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{thm}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\goldbach*

\begin{restatable}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
\label{thm:goldbach}
Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
\end{restatable}

\end{document}
```

I get an error -

```
undefined control sequence \goldbach
```

Is there any way to export these definitions so that they can be referred to before they are actually defined...?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do it the other way round, using the `restatable*` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{thm}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\begin{restatable*}[Goldbach's conjecture]{thm}{goldbach}
\label{thm:goldbach}
Every even integer greater than 2 can be expressed as the sum of two primes.
\end{restatable*}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{thm}
One
\end{thm}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{thm}
Two
\end{thm}

\lipsum[3]

\goldbach

\lipsum[3]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, I should have thought of that! Thanks!

Comment: There may be a problem if you are using `\include` to compile small pieces of your (large) document. If the definition of `\goldbach` lies under one usage of `include` but you reference the theorem, i.e use `\goldbach` under a different `\include`. This works against the idea of `\include`, forcing you to compile the separate `\include`'s simultaneously. Of course, I don't know what would be a reasonable solution to this conundrum. Just leaving a comment highlighting a potential caveat.

Comment: @LinearChristmas Yes, it cannot work with `\include`. But how useful is `\include` nowadays?

Comment: @egreg With my dear computer passing its first non-zero jubilee in base-10, `\include` is quite useful. :) Compiling 100+ page documents with many packages takes about 1 to 2.5 minutes. Broken into three parts, for instance, around 20 s.