# How can I cite the full content of a theorem?

Tags: citing

I wish to obtain a result like:

> Introduction
>
> ...
>
> And we will obtain the following Theorem:
>
> Theorem 2.X
>
> [statement of the theorem]
>
> ...
>
> 1. Section One
>
> ...
>
> 2. Section Two
>
> ...
>
> This gives
>
> Theorem 2.X
>
> [statement of the theorem]
>
> ...

And of course I don't want to input the theorem by hand in the introduction so that I have to update the number everytime I add some new theorem before my Theorem 2.X.

The best way that I can come up with is to use \cref for the number of theorem, say

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\crefname{theorem}{theorem}{theorems}


\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}
\Cref{label} 
\textit{[statement of the theorem]}

\section{Section One}

\section{Section Two}

\begin{theorem}\label{label}
[statement of the theorem]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This seems not bad, but I still have to do manually to keep the statements and the textstyle synchronous. Also, if I'm using tcbtheorem for my theorems, then I need to create a tcolorbox and make it have the same style to my boxes of theorems, and it would be tedious if I want to change the style someday.

I'd like to know if there is a better solution in which everything can be done automatically. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `thmtools` package defines *restatable* theorems through the `thm-restate` package.  Here is is the example in the manual, which shows how it is used:

```
\begin{restatable}[Euclid]{theorem}{firsteuclid}
\label{thm:euclid}%
For every prime $p$, there is a prime $p’>p$.
In particular, the list of primes,
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
2,3,45,7,\dots
\end{equation}
is infinite.
\end{restatable}
```

and to the right, I just use

```
\firsteuclid*
```

Comment: Thanks. I just searched restatable and found that this link solves my question. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113596/using-a-restatable-before-it-is-stated