# How to copy a lemma to appendix without changing its number?

Tags: theorems, labels

I have a document with a lemma (using `amsthm`), like so:

```
\begin{lem} \label{mylemma}
  % ...
\end{lem}

The proof of this lemma can be found in the appendix (see section \ref{sec:proof_of_mylemma}).
```

I now place a copy of the lemma in the appendix, with proof included:

```
\section{Appendix}

\section{Proof of lemma \ref{mylemma}} \label{sec:proof_of_my_lemma}

\begin{lem}
  % ...
\end{lem}

\begin{proof}
  % ...
\end{proof}
```

The problem is that the second copy of my lemma has a new number. How can I renumber this lemma to mimick the number of `mylemma`?

Thanks!

Comment: similar: [Recalling a theorem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51286/579) and [How do I repeat a theorem number?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422/579)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the `restatable` environment provided by the [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}{lem}{primelemma}
\label{mylemma}
Let $p$ be a prime number, and assume $p$ divides the product of two integers $a$ and $b$. Then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.
\end{restatable}

\section{Proof of lemma~\ref{mylemma}} 
\primelemma*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about the opposite: cite the lemma before? For example, cite on Introduction the Lema 1.2 with the same numbering.

Comment: @Sigur in that case, use the starred version `restatable*` in the Introduction and the un-starred `\primelemma` further on in the document.

Answer (score 1):

This really should be a comment rather than an answer, but I do not have sufficient reputation to comment. Hopefully someone will find this helpful and avoid some headache. You cannot use a number at the end of the reference. The following will fail:

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}{lem}{mylemma1}
\label{mylemma}
I claim that $1+1=2$.
\end{restatable}

\section{Proof of lemma~\ref{mylemma}} 
\mylemma1*

\end{document}
```

but the following will compile properly

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}{lem}{mylemmaone}
\label{mylemma}
I claim that $1+1=2$.
\end{restatable}

\section{Proof of lemma~\ref{mylemma}} 
\mylemmaone*

\end{document}
```