# How do you restate an algorithm?

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithm2e, content-replication

I'm trying to restate/repeat/recall an algorithm in an appendix with the same numbering, etc., but I haven't found an easy way to do it. I'm using the `algorithm` environment and `algorithm2e` package.

Ideally, I want something like the `restatable` environment in the `thmtools` package, but for algorithms instead of theorems. The answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158512/how-to-copy-a-lemma-to-appendix-without-changing-its-number) illustrates this with lemmas. Does this or something like it exist?

Edit: Here is a MWE using `restatable`:

```
\begin{restatable}{algorithm}{solver}  
\caption{Problem Solver}

Solve problem.

\end{restatable}

\appendix  
\section*{Appendix}

\solver*
```

This gives something like:

> #### Algorithm 1: Problem Solver
>
> **1** Solve problem.
>
> ## Appendix
>
> #### Algorithm 2: Problem Solver
>
> **1** Solve problem.

However, I would like both to say "Algorithm 1".

Comment: How many are we talking?  If < 200, you could store them all in saveboxes.

Comment: Haven't tried this. Can you simply put your algorithm environment inside a restatable theorem environment?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Algorithm doesn't seem to work with saveboxes. I get "not in outer par mode" error which I assume is because algorithm is a floating environment.

Comment: @EthanBolker This almost works just writing "\begin{restatable}{algorithm}{algname}". However, using "\algname*" to restate assigns a new number to the restated algorithm (even using * and compiling multiple times).

Comment: You can use a minipage inside a savebox, or use \setbox\mysavebox=\vbox{...}.  An MWE would be useful here.

Comment: Any updates on this demand ? Did you manage to find a solution yourself ?

Comment: See my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/690161/208544