# How to restate an algorithm with the same algorithm number?

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithmic, content-replication

I'm trying to have two copies of the same algorithm, with the same number twice in a paper. The `restatable` environment is able to reproduce the algorithm but introduces a new algorithm number each time it is restated.

For example:

```
\begin{restatable}{algorithm}{myAlgo}
   \vdots
\end{restatable}
% ...
\myAlgo*  % will introduce a new number, even when using *
```

**Question:** Is there a (simple) way to restate an algorithm while using the same number as before.

Note: this question is extremely [similar to this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318813/how-do-you-restate-an-algorithm). However, no answer was provided there and the question was (inexplicably, to me) closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counters that don't increment with `restatable` are stored in the comma-separated list `\thmt@innercounters`. By default it only contains `equation`. You can redefine this to use the algorithm counter, which at least for `algorithm2e` is `algocf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e,thmtools}

\makeatletter
\def\thmt@innercounters{equation,algocf}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{restatable}{algorithm}{myAlgo}
   \SetAlgoLined
   \KwData{this text}
   \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
   initialization\;
   \While{not at end of this document}{
   read current\;
   \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
   }
   }
   \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{restatable}

\myAlgo*

\end{document}
```

[image: algos]