# restate an equation

Tags: equations, equation-number

I know the `restatable` environment from the packages `thm-restate` combined with `thmtools`, which allows to formulate theorems that can be restated later in the document.

Now I am wondering, if there is a similar solution for equations like `equation`, `align`, etc.. I have already tried to just reuse that `restatable` environment for equations, but as expected I got an error.

I have already found "solutions" that suggestion to copy the content and tag the reference number. However, this seems to be a stopgap.

Comment: Have you tried using the cleveref package with the mathtools package to get the result?

Comment: I work with cleveref and mathtools, but I don't know what you mean. Can you be a little bit more specific? To which macro are you referring to?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406984/call-repeat-duplicate-equation-based-on-label

Answer (score 2):

The code below provides a command `\NewSavedEnvironment{<new-envname>}{<orig-envname>}` that defines an environment with syntax

```
\begin{<new-envname>}{customid}
\end{<new-envname>}
```

whose contents can be restated with `\customid*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{thmtools,amsmath}

\newenvironment{donothing}{}{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\NewSavedEnvironment}{m m}{
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{m +b}{%
        \begin{restatable}{donothing}{##1}
        \begin{#2}
        ##2
        \end{#2}
        \end{restatable}%
        }{\unskip\ignorespacesafterend}
    }

\NewSavedEnvironment{savedequation}{equation}
\NewSavedEnvironment{savedalign}{align}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{savedequation}{somename} \label{mylab}
\sum_i a_i
\end{savedequation}

\begin{savedalign}{anothername}
f: X &\to Y \\
x &\mapsto n\cdot x
\end{savedalign}

\somename*

\anothername*

\ref{mylab}

\end{document}
```

[image: equations]

If you want to use this for environments that don't use the `equation` counter, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/694557/208544).