# Collection of all definitions, theorems, etc. as flash cards

Tags: amsmath, content-replication, flashcards

Is there a way to collect all `definitions`, `theorems`, `corollary` etc. at the end of an document as flash cards in din a6 in `landscape`? Without copying all the data again?

So that the document contains text at the first pages and the last pages contains the flash cards?

Comment: This should be possible, but the way to it depends on the packages ;-)

Comment: I did not find a package which supports this. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: Well, I mean the packages you are using for the theorems etc. You did not show us a starter document

Comment: I am using the ams math package

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You can see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/recalling-a-theorem

Comment: @monoid -- `amsmath` doesn't have anything to do with theorems.  `amsthm` is the package involved there.  so you really do need to provide more information.