# How to automatically repeat all the theorems, propositions, definitions?

Tags: environments, content-replication

Suppose that you have a bunch of theorems, propositions, definitions and lemmas, like

> Definition 1. A group is said to be …
>   Lemma 2. Let … Then …
>   Proof 2. […]
>   Theorem 3. If … then …
>   Proof 3. […]

What I would like to do is to have a command like `\allResults` (or several like `\allTheorems`, `\allDefs`, `\allLemmas)` that returns at the end of the document the statements (without proofs) of the definitions, theorems, lemmas (in the correct order), like this:

> Definition 1. A group is said to be …
>   Lemma 2. Let … Then …
>   Theorem 3. If … then …

---

What I tried is to follow the answers to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251818) question. I didn't understand egreg's first code. I liked Andrew's code very much, but I wasn't able to change it for my situation.

Therefore I tried egreg's second code, by creating `\allprops` and `\alltheoremes`, but I got errors (see below), as if I created twice something... When I only create `\allprops` (without `\alltheoremes`), it works well.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{xparse}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Proposition,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmprop}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{prop}{o}
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_vedran_prop_int
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \vedran_restatable:x { \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_prop_int } }
   }
   {
    \vedran_restatable:nx { #1 } { \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_prop_int }     }
   }
 }
 {
  \endrestatable
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_vedran_prop_seq
   {
    prop \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_prop_int }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\allprops}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_vedran_prop_seq
   {
    \use:c { ##1 } *
   }
 }

\int_new:N \g_vedran_prop_int
\seq_new:N \g_vedran_prop_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \vedran_restatable:n #1
 {
  \restatable{thmprop}{prop#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vedran_restatable:n { x }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \vedran_restatable:nn #1 #2
 {
  \restatable[#1]{thmprop}{prop#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vedran_restatable:nn { nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\declaretheorem[
  name=Theoreme,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmtheoreme}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theoreme}{o}
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_vedran_theoreme_int
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \vedran_restatable:x { \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_theoreme_int } }
   }
   {
    \vedran_restatable:nx { #1 } { \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_theoreme_int } }
   }
 }
 {
  \endrestatable
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_vedran_theoreme_seq
   {
    theoreme \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_theoreme_int }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\alltheoremes}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_vedran_theoreme_seq
   {
    \use:c { ##1 } *
   }
 }

\int_new:N \g_vedran_theoreme_int
\seq_new:N \g_vedran_theoreme_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \vedran_restatable:n #1
 {
  \restatable{thmtheoreme}{theoreme#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vedran_restatable:n { x }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \vedran_restatable:nn #1 #2
 {
  \restatable[#1]{thmtheoreme}{theoreme#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vedran_restatable:nn { nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\section{Originals}
Some text.

\begin{prop}[Euler]
This is the first prop.
\end{prop}

Some text.

\begin{prop}
This is the second prop.
\end{prop}

Some text.

\section{All together}
\allprops

\end{document}
```

I get errors like

```
LaTeX error: "kernel/command-already-defined"
!
! Control sequence \vedran_restatable:n already defined.
```

My question is: how is it possible to create commands like `\allResults` (or several like `\allTheorems`, `\allDefs`, `\allLemmas`), either by changing my code, or by using a new and better idea (e.g. egreg's or Andrew's answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251818/how-to-automatically-repeat-all-the-theorems/251845?noredirect=1#comment848875_251845))?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You have copied the definitions of `\vedran_restatable` more than once

Comment: @ChristianHupfer : thank you for your comment! Does it mean that I can't use some kind of "restatable" to solve my problem (since I have several environments Theorem, Definition, Proposition, Lemma, to deal with)?

Comment: Basically,  as is setup by egreg you need a `....restatable` macro for each theorem type. This can be done in loop, most likely, but requires more work to do. (I am short of time, right now)

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74857/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that (as it is defined right now) there must be an individual `\vedran_...restatable` macro for each of the theorem-like environment.

I am short of time right now, but I'll try to provide a more sophisticated approach for more than just two environments.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{xparse}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Proposition,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmprop}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{prop}{o}
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_vedran_prop_int
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \vedran_restatable:x { \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_prop_int } }
   }
   {
    \vedran_restatable:nx { #1 } { \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_prop_int } }
   }
 }
 {
  \endrestatable
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_vedran_prop_seq
   {
    prop \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_prop_int }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\allprops}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_vedran_prop_seq
   {
    \use:c { ##1 } *
   }
 }

\int_new:N \g_vedran_prop_int
\seq_new:N \g_vedran_prop_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \vedran_restatable:n #1
 {
  \restatable{thmprop}{prop#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vedran_restatable:n { x }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \vedran_restatable:nn #1 #2
 {
  \restatable[#1]{thmprop}{prop#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vedran_restatable:nn { nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff







\declaretheorem[
  name=Theoreme,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmtheoreme}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment{theoreme}{o}
 {
  \int_gincr:N \g_vedran_theoreme_int
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
   {
    \vedran_theo_restatable:x { \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_theoreme_int } }
   }
   {
    \vedran_theo_restatable:nx { #1 } { \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_theoreme_int } }
   }
 }
 {
  \endrestatable
  \seq_gput_right:Nx \g_vedran_theoreme_seq
   {
    theoreme \int_to_Alph:n { \g_vedran_theoreme_int }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\alltheoremes}{}
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_vedran_theoreme_seq
   {
    \use:c { ##1 } *
   }
 }

\int_new:N \g_vedran_theoreme_int
\seq_new:N \g_vedran_theoreme_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \vedran_theo_restatable:n #1
 {
  \restatable{thmtheoreme}{theoreme#1}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vedran_theo_restatable:n { x }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \vedran_theo_restatable:nn #1 #2
 {
  \restatable[#1]{thmtheoreme}{theoreme#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \vedran_theo_restatable:nn { nx }
\ExplSyntaxOff







\begin{document}

\section{Originals}

Some text.

\begin{prop}[Euler]
This is the first prop.
\end{prop}

Some text.

\begin{prop}
This is the second prop.
\end{prop}

Some text.

\begin{theoreme}
foo foo
\end{theoreme}

\section{All together}

\alltheoremes

\allprops

\end{document}
```

**Update**

Generic code generation with `\AddDeclaredTheorems{...}` will produce all relevant macros and environments on the fly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{xparse}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Proposition,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmprop}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Theoreme,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmtheoreme}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Example,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmexample}


\ExplSyntaxOn


\seq_new:N \g_vedran_declaredtheorem_seq

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_generate_variant:Nn { cn } % Does this work????
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_to_Alph:n {c}

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddDeclaredTheorems}{m}{%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  % Loop over elements in the list and add them to the list of declared theorems
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_vedran_declaredtheorem_seq {##1}
  }
  \seq_gremove_duplicates:N \g_vedran_declaredtheorem_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_vedran_declaredtheorem_seq {%
    \int_if_exist:cF { g_vedran_##1_int } {
      \int_new:c {g_vedran_##1_int}
    }
    \seq_if_exist:cTF { g_vedran_##1_seq }{%
      \seq_gclear:c { g_vedran_##1_seq }
    }{% No, does not exist, define it
      \seq_new:c { g_vedran_##1_seq }
    }
    \vedran_generate_restatable_noopt:n {##1}
    \vedran_generate_restatable_opt:n {##1}
    %Build the variants
    \cs_generate_variant:cn { vedran_##1_restatable:n } { x }
    \cs_generate_variant:cn { vedran_##1_restatable:nn } { nx }
    \vedran_generate_wrapper_env:n {##1}
    \vedran_generate_allthingies:n {##1}
  }% End of \seq_map_inline
}

\cs_new:Nn \vedran_generate_restatable_noopt:n {%
  \cs_if_exist:cF { vedran_#1_restatable:n } {
    \cs_new_protected:cn {vedran_#1_restatable:n}{%
      \typeout{Using vedran_#1_restatable:x}%
      \restatable{thm#1}{#1##1}
    }
  }
}

\cs_new:Nn \vedran_generate_restatable_opt:n {
  \cs_if_exist:cF { vedran_#1_restatable:nn } {
    \cs_new_protected:cn {vedran_#1_restatable:nn }{%
      \restatable[##1]{thm#1}{#1##2}
    }
  }
}


\cs_new:Nn \vedran_generate_wrapper_env:n {%
  \cs_if_exist:cF {#1} {
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{o}
    {
      \int_gincr:c { g_vedran_#1_int }
      \IfNoValueTF{##1}
      {
        \use:c{vedran_#1_restatable:x} { \int_to_Alph:c { g_vedran_#1_int } }
      }
      {
        \use:c{vedran_#1_restatable:nx} { ##1 } { \int_to_Alph:c { g_vedran_#1_int } }
      }
    }
    {
      \endrestatable
      \seq_gput_right:cx  {g_vedran_#1_seq} {#1\int_to_Alph:c { g_vedran_#1_int }}
    }
  }
}

\cs_new:Nn \vedran_generate_allthingies:n {
  \cs_new:cpn {all#1s} 
  {
    \seq_map_inline:cn {g_vedran_#1_seq}
    {
      \use:c { ####1 } *
    }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddDeclaredTheorems{prop,theoreme,example}

\section{Originals}

Some text.

\begin{prop}[Euler]
This is the first prop.
\end{prop}

\begin{example}
  $E=mc^2$
\end{example}

Some text.

\begin{prop}
This is the second prop.
\end{prop}

Some text.

\begin{theoreme}
foo foo
\end{theoreme}

\section{All together}

\alltheoremes

\allprops

\allexamples

\end{document}
```

**Next Update -- with `\AllThingiesInOrderOfAppearance` command

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{xparse}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Proposition,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmprop}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Theoreme,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmtheoreme}

\declaretheorem[
  name=Example,
  numberwithin=section,
]{thmexample}


\ExplSyntaxOn


\seq_new:N \g_vedran_declaredtheorem_seq

\seq_new:N \g_vedran_ordered_seq 

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_generate_variant:Nn { cn } % Does this work????
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_to_Alph:n {c}

\NewDocumentCommand{\AddDeclaredTheorems}{m}{%
  \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
  % Loop over elements in the list and add them to the list of declared theorems
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_vedran_declaredtheorem_seq {##1}
  }
  \seq_gremove_duplicates:N \g_vedran_declaredtheorem_seq
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_vedran_declaredtheorem_seq {%
    \int_if_exist:cF { g_vedran_##1_int } {
      \int_new:c {g_vedran_##1_int}
    }
    \seq_if_exist:cTF { g_vedran_##1_seq }{%
      \seq_gclear:c { g_vedran_##1_seq }
    }{% No, does not exist, define it
      \seq_new:c { g_vedran_##1_seq }
    }
    \vedran_generate_restatable_noopt:n {##1}
    \vedran_generate_restatable_opt:n {##1}
    %Build the variants
    \cs_generate_variant:cn { vedran_##1_restatable:n } { x }
    \cs_generate_variant:cn { vedran_##1_restatable:nn } { nx }
    \vedran_generate_wrapper_env:n {##1}
    \vedran_generate_allthingies:n {##1}
  }% End of \seq_map_inline
}

\cs_new:Nn \vedran_generate_restatable_noopt:n {%
  \cs_if_exist:cF { vedran_#1_restatable:n } {
    \cs_new_protected:cn {vedran_#1_restatable:n}{%
      \restatable{thm#1}{#1##1}
    }
  }
}

\cs_new:Nn \vedran_generate_restatable_opt:n {
  \cs_if_exist:cF { vedran_#1_restatable:nn } {
    \cs_new_protected:cn {vedran_#1_restatable:nn }{%
      \restatable[##1]{thm#1}{#1##2}
    }
  }
}


\cs_new:Nn \vedran_generate_wrapper_env:n {%
  \cs_if_exist:cF {#1} {
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{#1}{o}
    {
      \int_gincr:c { g_vedran_#1_int }
      \IfNoValueTF{##1}
      {
        \use:c{vedran_#1_restatable:x} { \int_to_Alph:c { g_vedran_#1_int } }
      }
      {
        \use:c{vedran_#1_restatable:nx} { ##1 } { \int_to_Alph:c { g_vedran_#1_int } }
      }
    }
    {
      \endrestatable
      \seq_gput_right:cx  {g_vedran_#1_seq} {#1\int_to_Alph:c { g_vedran_#1_int }}
      \seq_gput_right:Nx  \g_vedran_ordered_seq {#1\int_to_Alph:c { g_vedran_#1_int }}
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\AllThingiesInOrderOfAppearance}{}{%
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_vedran_ordered_seq {%
    \use:c {##1} *
  }
}

\cs_new:Nn \vedran_generate_allthingies:n {
  \cs_new:cpn {all#1s} 
  {
    \seq_map_inline:cn {g_vedran_#1_seq}
    {
      \use:c { ####1 } *
    }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\AddDeclaredTheorems{prop,theoreme,example}

\section{Originals}

Some text.

\begin{prop}[Euler]
This is the first prop.
\end{prop}

\begin{example}
  $E=mc^2$
\end{example}

Some text.

\begin{prop}
This is the second prop.
\end{prop}

Some text.

\begin{theoreme}
foo foo
\end{theoreme}

\section{All together}

% All in order
\AllThingiesInOrderOfAppearance


% Individual ones in a row

Now individual groups:

\alltheoremes

\allprops

\allexamples

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It will be very useful, I think. However, we get here first all the theorems, and then all the propositions. Do you know if it is possible to create some kind of `\allResults` which gives the theorems and propositions in _the same order_ as in the original section?

Comment: @Watson: Should be possible, again, later on...

Comment: Is it possible to have in the example above Theorem 1.3 instead of Theorem 1.1. (using `\usepackage{amsthm}`and `\theoremstyle{plain}` makes no sense here)? Many thanks!

Comment: I had no time yet

Comment: Sorry to ask you again, but did you have time to think about my question to create something like `\allResults` ? Thank you! :-)

Comment: @Watson: I'll try during the next days. I had very busy days...

Comment: @Watson: See the update at the end of the post

Comment: Just one last question: do you know if it is possible to have the results appearing in the same order in the section "All Together" as in the "Originals"? Here we have first all the theorems, then the props, finally the examples, which is not the same order as in "Originals".

Comment: @Watson: Sigh...

Comment: @Watson: See the next update at the end of my post

Comment: That's really impressive. Sorry for having asked for these edits. Thank very much again! :-)

Comment: @Watson: Well... yes... I will update later on (no, not today ;-)) with a better checking whether the wrapper environment has been defined already. I am a little bit unsatisfied with the way I've done it yet (it's quick and dirty ;-))