# Restating a listing

Tags: cross-referencing, listings, content-replication

I have a listing that I want to restate at some later point. How can I do this, without creating a new index for the restated listing?

My best approach so far has been to put the listing twice, which creates a new index for the second occurrence. If the label of the two duplicated listing is not changed, this in addition lead to a naming conflict.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Code,label=lst:code]
    x:=1;
\end{lstlisting}
Here, we introduce Listing~\ref{lst:code}.
\section{Two}
For convenience, we restate Listing~\ref{lst:code} here.
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Code,label=lst:code]
    x:=1;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture]

How do I avoid this?

Ideally, I would like to restate the listing without having to repeat its contents explicitly (this is possible for e.g. Lemmas using `thm-restate`). Essentially, I would like to obtain the same result as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/recalling-a-theorem), but for listings.

Comment: Remove the caption of the 2nd listing and there will no 'index', i.e. a number. By the way, you're using the same label twice, which is a logical error

Comment: This still requires to duplicate the Listing. Ideally, I would like to avoid that. Also, I do want a caption for the 2nd listing. Essentially, the second listing should be a duplication of the first one.

Comment: `\lstinputlisting` could help to avoid the duplication of the content.

Comment: Using `title=` instead of `caption=` for the second occurrence should prevent the additional label and index entry. Alternatively, try the `nolol` option to prevent inclusion of the second listing into the list of listings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to externalise the listings's content as an extra file inserted with `\lstinputlisting` and construct the caption of the second instance from the label set in the first instance:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings,hyperref,filecontents}
\begin{document}

% only for MWE purposes (to create a file we can load with \lstinputlisting)
\begin{filecontents*}{mycode.pas}
  x:=1;
\end{filecontents*}


\section{One}
\lstinputlisting[caption=Code,label=lst:code]{mycode.pas}
Here, we introduce Listing~\ref{lst:code}.

\section{Two}
For convenience, we restate Listing~\ref{lst:code} here.
\lstinputlisting[title=\lstlistingname~\ref{lst:code}: \nameref{lst:code}]{mycode.pas}
\end{document}
```

[image]