# Numbering of Theorem/Lemma

Tags: numbering

I have some lemma (let's call it lemma 4) in my main text, but I prove it in the appendix. Therefore, I want to restate the lemma in the appendix again as lemma 4. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add a minimal example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `thm-restate` package of `thmtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{thm-restate}

\declaretheorem{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\section{First}    
\begin{restatable}{Lemma}{lemmfour}
    \label{lemm:4}
    Content of Lemma~4.
\end{restatable}


\section{Second}
\lemmfour*

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use the `thm-restate` package which is part of `thmtools`. See for example the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/recalling-a-theorem).

Comment: Could you please add an example code, which solves the issue stated in the question, to make your answer clearer?