# How can I define a command like `\copypaste{ref-label}`?

Tags: macros, environments, labels

How can I have a command like `\copypaste{ref-label}` such that it copy the corresponding environment to label `\label{ref-label}`  and paste it where the command `\copypaste{ref-label}` is? or at least (if this is easier) two commands `\copy{ref-label}` (placing inside of the environment) and `\paste{ref-label}` (where we want to paste)?

I know that this commands may be useless but it is interesting and useful for me because sometimes I want to quote some lemmas, definitions,... from earlier chapters. Of course I can define new environments (new def, lem ,thm, ...) and set their counter to corresponding environment.

Comment: The `\label`-command is already defined and the concepts belonging to the `\label..\ref`-mechanism are well established since decades and therefore should not be distorted. You'd need to give your command another name. In any case a problem is: When you have LaTeX (re)set whatsoever counters to former values, the likelihood is high that this will break the `hyperref` package which forms names of destinations/referencing anchors from the current values and names of the corresponding counters while names of referencing anchors must be unique. Apart from that you could .. (see my next comment)

Comment: (this is my next comment) ...  Apart from that you could have LaTeX read things under verbatim-category-code régime (probably taking horizontal tab into account) and store things (including counter-values) in a macro and for referencing apply `\scantokens` to the expansion of that macro. This could even be done with an intermediate step via the .aux-file so that referencing before the thing occurs in the main text is possible.

Comment: @C.F.G has reviewed the answer that I proposed?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL: Unfortunately, package in your answer, needs `texlive 2019` but I have `texlive 2018` and your answer don't works for me. Also I tried to install v 2019 but failed. see [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518768).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scontents}
\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
\section{Definitions}
Some text here...

\begin{scontents}[print-env=true,store-env=definitions]
First definition stored in memory.
\end{scontents}

More text here...

\begin{scontents}[print-env=true,store-env=definitions]
Second definition stored in memory.
\end{scontents}

\section{Other section}
Another little bit of text here, now I bring the definitions
I saved in memory...

\getstored[2]{definitions}\par

In reverse order

\getstored[1]{definitions}

\section{One more time}
Okay, I'll reoccupy the definitions, but in the right order.

\getstored[1]{definitions}\par
\getstored[2]{definitions}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The [scontents](https://ctan.org/pkg/scontents) package is designed to do this job, I have used the `environment` version, but you can also use the `command` version. If you have `verbatim` material is also supported and if you want to *write to external files*, well, you can also do it :).

Comment: Finally I installed TexLive 2019. When I use `Theorem` env. it works very well but it changes the theorem counter of stored `Theorem` env.

Comment: `\begin{scontents}[print-env=true,store-env=definitions]
\begin{theorem}
Theorem stored in memory.
\end{theorem}
\end{scontents}`

Comment: @C.F.G I think you need to renew the associated counter before running `getstored` (untested).

Comment: How to renew the associated counter without effecting on next theorem? It seems that there is no other solution for my question. so I accept your answer.

Comment: @C.F.G If only theorems and definitions are involved, the most appropriate approach would be to use `thmtools` and `thm-restate`, perhaps this can help you (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51288/7832).

Comment: Thank you so much for answer and last link.