# How to refer the whole contents and avoid code repetition in theorem?

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I've a bunch of theorems

```
\section{maybe 2}
\begin{Theorem}an interesting theorem\end{Theorem} # Theorem 1
\begin{Theorem}a boring theorem\end{Theorem}
% n lines ommited
\section{maybe 10}
\begin{Theorem}the last interesting theorem\end{Theorem} # Theorem 233
```

And I'd like to ref the whole contents some of the first section

```
\section{Highlights}
\begin{Theorem}an interesting theorem\end{Theorem} # numbering 1
# m (<< n) lines ommited
\begin{Theorem}the last interesting theorem\end{Theorem} # numbering 233
```

Is these any elegant way to refer to whole contexts of some theorems, without directly copying and pasting the code, an manually setting the counter?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51288/134144 could be interesting.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Can you please clarify: do you want to *refer* to the theorem or do you want to *repeat* it (even with the same number)