# Use the same number for the same theorem

Tags: counters

I state a theorem first, and want to write the proof in the later section. And I want to restate the theorem when I am going to prove it. So in the whole paper, I write the theorem for two times, but I want them have the same number. How can i do this?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422/34551 If you restate _exactly_ the same theorem, you can use restatable, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51288/34551

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `thm-restate` which is part of [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package.

It offers an environment called `restatable`. The star `*` is always indicating, where the Theorem is *cited*.

So

```
\begin{restatable}[Theorem A]{thm}{thmA}\label{thmA}
If A then B.
\end{restatable}
```

And later recall it by

```
\thmA*
```

would produce the Theorem number first, then cite it. Where, on the other hand,

```
\begin{restatable*}[Theorem A]{thm}{thmA}\label{thmA}
If A then B.
\end{restatable*}
```

And later recall it by

```
\thmA
```

would get the number of the section, where "\thmA" is used.