# Write something in two places at once

Tags: cross-referencing

The crux of my question is essentially what's in the title. I shall elaborate more now.

---

### The Problem

I am planning on writing notes for a math course I had taken and I want it to be a summary of sorts which I can quickly refer to, in the future.
Due to this, I wish to write it in a way that I have all my Definitions, Theorems, Lemma, et cetera in one place without proofs in the middle.

However, I do want to include proofs at the end, for the times I want a more in-depth recap. Therefore, I wish to add a section at the end which would have the proofs as well.

Here is how I want the structure to be:

```
Section 1. The Quick Recap
 Theorem 1. Riemann Hypothesis
 // other theorems, definition, et cetera 
 //...

---

Section 2. The Proofs
 Theorem 1. Riemann Hypothesis
 Proof. // Proof of Theorem 1.
```

Getting back to the title, the Theorems are exactly what I'd want to be written twice. Of course, I could just copy and paste every single one but I feel like there should be a better alternative. (Especially if I wish to make changes later.) In particular, the numbering should be the same.

---

### My Thoughts

I believe it's considered good practice to show what I've researched, so I have written a possible attempt of my own.
However, **I am completely fine if your solution has something completely different**. (In particular, you may skip this section.)

I do have an idea of sorts of what command definition could help me solve this problem but I have no idea how to actually write one. Here is the way I think it could possibly be solved:

We define a command `copy` which accepts two arguments: `text` and `label`. The `text` would contain the thing that is to be copied. In the above example, it would be "Theorem 1." (and its statement). The `label` would be the identifier that will help me reference it later. (Similar to how we have `\label{}` and `\ref{}`.)

Conversely, we could define a command `paste` which takes one argument - `label`. Naturally, this would be the label that would help me refer to the original `text` and then display it.

A possible error - If I use a countered environment in `text` (like for Theorems or Lemmas), I fear that it while pasting it blindly, it might actually update the counter and renumber the theorem. I wouldn't want something like this. While I could just reset the counter before the Proofs section, this would pose a problem if I skip the proofs of some theorems in between.

---

### MWE

I am aware that usually, people prefer if an MWE is given but I think that that should not be required in this case. I will be using the document class `article` and the standard math packages.

I hope that I've been clear with what I want. I have tried to keep it as bare as possible.

---

### Additional requirement

Here I describe an additional requirement which I would appreciate. However, **it is okay if your answer does not have this.**

The requirement is:
In section 1, I would like the text "Theorem 1." to be hyperlinked to take me to the proof of "Theorem 1." in section 2. Conversely, the "Theorem 1." in section 2 should be hyperlinked to bring me back.

Comment: Yoo could abuse of `xsim` (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/xsim/doc/xsim_manual.pdf) using theorems for questions and proofs for answers.

Comment: Maybe it will give some insight to you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51286/recalling-a-theorem

Comment: @JairoADelRio: Thank you! The second answer seems to be the thing I was looking for. (Save for the additional requirement.) Are you aware if there's any way to refer to restated theorem?