# keep numbering in appendix

Tags: numbering, appendices

I have a question about the numbering in the appendix.

I want to proof a Lemma in the appendix which I used in the normal sections of my thesis.
Therefore, I want to state the Lemma again in the appendix, followed by the proof. But I would like to keep the numbering of the Lemma the same as where I first used it instead of having them numbered with (A.1) etc.

Example:

In the normal chapters:

> Lemma 3.7
>
> statement and formular (3.21)

Then in the Appendix it should also stay like this:

> Appendix
>
> Lemma 3.7
>
> ....
>
> Proof:
>
> In order to proof equation (3.21), we have to....
>
> \end proof

I hope it is clear, what I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number, but there is another question here which can restate the environment completely. I'm on mobile and cannot find it. (And welcome to TeX.SX!)

Comment: You can use a stared version of the `\newtheorem` and change its `theoremstyle` to format in the same way. Then you can use `\begin{lemaX}[Lemma~\ref{lema3.7}] \end{lemaX}`.

Answer (score 1):

I use this commands and it works for me:

```
\newcommand{\seepage}[1]{\marginpar{\scriptsize (p.~\pageref{#1})}}
\newenvironment{lemmafirst}[1]{\begin{lemma}\label{#1}\seepage{#1_appendix}
}{\end{lemma}}
\newenvironment{lemmaagain}[1]{\begin{trivlist}\label{#1_appendix}
\item[] \textbf{Lemma~\ref{#1}.} \seepage{#1} \em}{\end{trivlist}}
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Additionally, explaining a bit more about how this works and/or giving a complete MWE might be helpful.