# How to repeat a conjecture

Tags: theorems

I am writing my dissertation (the document class is `report` if that makes any difference) and would like to repeat two conjectures which I state in the introduction in a later chapter. The conjecture environment I currently have is:

```
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
```

and my conjecture looks like this:

```
\begin{conjecture}\label{r paths}
At most $r$ disjoint monochromatic paths are needed to cover the vertices of any r-edge-coloured $K_n$.
\end{conjecture}
```

Edit: Sorry for not being clearer, I would like the conjecture to have the same number both times in my document.

Comment: What is your question?  Do you want to know how to make the numbering identical in the introduction and in the chapter?

Comment: Have a look at `thmtools` package. It allows you to repeat theorems.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, I want the conjectures to have the same number and it is not a theorem so I can't use these solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
```

and in the body of your document:

```
\begin{restatable}{conjecture}{PathsConj}\label{r paths}
At most $r$ disjoint monochromatic paths are needed to cover the vertices of any r-edge-coloured $K_n$.
\end{restatable}
```

where you state the conjecture, and

```
\PathsConj*
```

at the place where you want to restate it.

As you can see, it works somewhat like the `empheq` environment for amsmath environments: you use a `restatable` environment, with two mandatory arguments: the name of the theorem-like environment, and the name of the command which will be used to restate the environment. If the environment  uses the optional argument (e.g. `Conjecture of My Self`), it must be given as an optional argument of the `restatable` environment.

Comment: Thank you, although this seems to give me different numbers for the two conjectures. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: I don't understand very well: do you mean  you want to repeat two conjectures, or just one, and the number of the repeated conjecture is not the same as the number  of the original conjecture?

Comment: I want to repeat just one conjecture, and I want the both copies of the conjecture to have the same number. Thanks!

Comment: But that's what it does! You must have something else in your code. Could you post  an example?

Comment: What should I post? I have copied your code exactly and the first copy of the conjecture (in the introduction) has number 1 and the second copy has number 85 :/