# How to number Corollaries by Lemmas

Tags: numbering

I am looking to number my corollaries similarly to how [Serre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean-Pierre_Serre) does it.  His corollary numbers mirror the Lemma or Proposition which they follow.  For example:

```
Section 1
Proposition 1
Corollary 1
Lemma 1.1
Corollary 1.1

Section 2
Lemma 2.1
Proposition 2
Lemma 2.2
Corollary 2.2A
Corollary 2.2B
```

How to do something similar in LaTeX?  I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
\begin{lem}\label{l1}
...
\end{lem}
\begin{cor}\label{c1}\tag{\ref{l1}}
...
\end{cor}
```

However, this gives me a syntax error.  [see full code below]

I also tried using [reptheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number) for this; however, it does not seem to be quite suited to this task; and I am not good enough at LaTeX coding to modify it to make it work here.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Lem}[lem]{Lemma}%*
\numberwithin{lem}{section}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Prop}[prop]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Cor}{Corollary}%}[lem]{
\newtheorem{cor}[Cor]{Corollary}%*
\begin{document}
\section{asdf}
\begin{lem}\label{l1}
\end{lem}
\begin{prop}\label{p1}
\end{prop}
\begin{cor}\label{c1}\tag{\ref{l1}}
\end{cor}
\section{fdsa}
\begin{lem}\label{l2}
\end{lem}
\begin{prop}\label{p2}
\end{prop}
\begin{lem}\label{l2}
\end{lem}
\begin{cor}\label{c2}\tag{\ref{l2}A}
%\tag{asdf}
\end{cor}
\begin{cor}\label{c3}\tag{\ref{l2}B}
%\tag{asdf}
\end{cor}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far, not only fragments

Comment: My computer with LaTeX does not have internet access, so I have to transfer to a different computer to give the code sample; also, I'm not sure how much use my attempt is, since it did generate a syntax error.  However, due to your request, I spent 13 minutes to upload a code sample.  Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any consistency in the numbering scheme for corollaries. It seems conditional on the number of corollaries per lemma?

Comment: @Werner Yes.  Per Lemma, or per Proposition.  That's the way Serre does it.

Comment: @Alex: Who is Serre?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Jean-Pierre Serre, the famous 80-year-old mathematician...

Comment: @Alex... seems to be famous for strange numbering schemes ... perhaps useful in topology ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :)  No, he's just a very perfectionist algebraist.  My adviser recalled how when he met Serre, Serre upbraided him for saying "The following 10 lemmas" in a paper, instead of spelling the "ten" out; he said that when numerals are used, they have to denote mathematical objects...  But in either case, that's irrelevant to how to make LaTeX repeat his numbering.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Alex: So Lemmas (per section) and Propositions (stand-alone) are numbered differently, yet both have (possibly) sub-numbered Corollaries?

Comment: @Werner Yes, that is correct.  I figured out how to number this before you posted; however, I'm now having trouble referring back to the numbers.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346499/how-to-refer-to-corollaries-numbered-by-lemmas

Comment: French mathematicians are known for their peculiar numbering systems, which seem to be devised very carefully in order that the reader is not able to find the statement from the reference. With due respect to one of the greatest mathematicians of the 20th century, I find this particular numbering system one of the silliest. On the other hand, I fully agree that ”the following 10 lemmas“ is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an implementation, which might be improved for cross-references.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newtheorem{propT}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemmaT}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem*{genericT}{\genericTname}

\newenvironment{prop}{\propT}{\endpropT\xdef\laststatement{\thepropT}}
\newenvironment{lem}{\lemmaT}{\endlemmaT\xdef\laststatement{\thelemmaT}}

\newenvironment{corollary}[1][]
 {\def\genericTname{Corollary \laststatement#1}\genericT}
 {\endgenericT}

\begin{document}

\section{asdf}
\begin{prop}
\end{prop}
\begin{corollary}
\end{corollary}
\begin{lem}
\end{lem}
\begin{corollary}
\end{corollary}

\section{fdsa}
\begin{lem}
\end{lem}
\begin{prop}
\end{prop}
\begin{lem}
\end{lem}
\begin{corollary}[A]
\end{corollary}
\begin{corollary}[B]
\end{corollary}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Personal comment.* With due respect to one of the greatest mathematicians of the 20th century, this numbering scheme is silly. Especially devised for making it difficult to find a statement from a reference in the text: for instance, where the h*** will Proposition 24 be? Now add theorems: can you tell whether Proposition 18 is before or after Theorem 3? No, of course: you have no clue even about what section they are in. However, I've seen worse systems.

## Addition

If you want to refer to corollaries with `\label`, I *think* this can work. Change the definition of `corollary` into

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{corollary}[1][]
 {%
  \def\genericTname{Corollary \laststatement#1}%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\laststatement#1}%
  \genericT
 }
 {\endgenericT}
\makeatletter
```

Now

```
\begin{corollary}[B]\label{whatever}
```

should make it possible to use `\ref{whatever}` and get “2.2B” (assuming the numbering of the example above).

Comment: Might not work so well for a book-- but in a thesis, where I have 2-3 theorems each within their own section, and the rest are propositions, lemmas, and corollaries, this particular method is particularly useful.  Cor 2.3B means the second Corollary to the third Lemma related to the second Theorem.  The reason Propositions are numbered individually is, to make referencing them in future works easier, because they are major statements which are likely to be cited.  +1 for the \laststatement

Comment: @Alex I fully disagree about the usefulness of this method. ;-)

Comment: So I tried to improve this for cross-references, and one problem is, `\thecor` is undefined for this implementation.  How do I change the `\ref`ed-to underlying number?  Alternatively, how do I access the optional parameter when I am doing `\renewcommand{\thecor}` using a traditional implementation?

Comment: @Alex It makes no sense to cross reference a corollary: reference its parent object.

Comment: But the "A" or "B" or "" might change as I move corollaries around.  Then I would have to update all references when I move corollaries.

Comment: @Alex I added the proper code. I *believe* it works, but I'm surely not going to spend much more time on something I find hideous.

Comment: Yes, this worked.  Should I update the original code?

Answer (score 1):

Got it!  With a modification to reptheorem.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newtheorem*{rep@theorem}{\rep@title}
\newcommand{\newreptheorem}[2]{%
\newenvironment{rep#1}[2][]{%
 \def\rep@title{#2 \ref{##2}##1}%
 \begin{rep@theorem}}%
 {\end{rep@theorem}}}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\newreptheorem{lem}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Lem}[lem]{Lemma}%*
\numberwithin{lem}{section}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\newreptheorem{prop}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Prop}[prop]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Cor}{Corollary}%}[lem]{
\newtheorem{cor}[Cor]{Corollary}%*
\begin{document}
\section{asdf}
\begin{lem}\label{l1}
\end{lem}
\begin{prop}\label{p1}
\end{prop}
\begin{repprop}{p1}
\end{repprop}
\section{fdsa}
\begin{lem}\label{l2}
\end{lem}
\begin{prop}\label{p2}
\end{prop}
\begin{lem}\label{l2}
\end{lem}
\begin{replem}[A]{l2}
\end{replem}
\begin{replem}[B]{l2}
\end{replem}
\end{document}
```