# Restate Theorem with given theorem setup

Tags: theorems

I am given the follwoing theorem setup, which I have to use.

```
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}  
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]  
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}  
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}  
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}  
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}  
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}  
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

How is it possible to restate a theorem with the same number as when stated first. I don't mind if I have to rewrite the theorem or even put the number in by hand, because I only need it once.

Comment: does it help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422/how-do-i-repeat-a-theorem-number

Comment: I tried several option from this question already. But none seemed to work.

Comment: Then I propose you provide a complete and minimal document (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) with an example of what have you tested and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by changing the setup a bit.

```
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}  
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]  
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}  
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}  
\newtheorem*{thm345}{Theorem 3.45}
\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}  
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}  
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\square}}  
\newtheorem{proof}{Proof}
```

Now using:

```
\begin{thm345}
theorem text
\end{thm345}
```

gives me what I want